# How can I remove or clone a disk in the storage pool?

Tags: windows-server-2012, storage-spaces

So I have a storage pool with a few disks in it and one of them is on its way out. The bad disk is a 2TB and the one I just bought to replace it is a 3TB. At first, all I wanted to do was clone the the bad disk contents onto the new drive with Paragon, but I can't see the bad disk in order to start the clone. I figured maybe I needed to remove it from the pool first, so I went through a number of tutorials to do so but didn't really get anywhere. I got as far as to have the drive marked as "retired" but when I choose "remove disk" it says that it is attached to a virtual disk that uses simple layout and that in order to remove it, I would have to delete the virtual disk... uh... ouch? Doesn't that mean I lose everything? It's a 9TB virtual disk with all of my movies, tv shows, music, etc on it.

Is there a way around this? How can I replace this disk with the new one?

Answer (score 1):

This is why any of the non-redundant types of storage spaces are BAD.  There is no way to move them to new disks.  Even if the disks work fine, and you have room to add a new disk, you can't even do a disk by disk upgrade.

Your only option is to delete the entire virtual disk and create a new one.

If you make your new one a parity space, you'll save yourself the pain of going through this again.  Parity spaces do allow you to remove one drive and rebuild the data on a new drive.

If you are using this primarily archiving large media files, storage spaces probably isn't the best solution for you.  Something more like [StableBit DrivePool](https://stablebit.com/DrivePool) would probably serve you better - it just takes a bunch of drives and spreads the files out over them, presenting it as a single volume.  Everything is still treated as normal files on an NTFS partition, so rearranging things later is easy.